# Create composite and custom grid control in ASP.Net 2008 or above

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Please suggest me how  to create composite grid. ie , i need  all the features of gridview in the Framework 3.5 and above,but also need to include some other functionality to that grid.please suggest me what to do . if possible please share sample code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to extend the current GridView. Example:

```
public class MySuperGridView : GridView
{

    public void CoolMethod()
    {
    }

    public string CoolProperty 
   {
       get{return ViewState["CoolProperty"]==null?null:(string)ViewState["CoolProperty"];}
       set {ViewState ["CoolProperty"]=value;}
   }
    //add more coolness here
}
```

Now you can start using your custom Gridview instead of the standard asp.net GridView

Comment: Thanks for quick responds,one thing  how possible ,put  gridview in the DIV in composite control.So i need to access all the  gridview property from aspx page.

Comment: @Justinonday you just need to register this control on your page and use it... here is a [good place to start](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering.aspx).

Comment: ok..i mean that ,i need to access all the events of gridview.also need to acces div in from javascript...more clear how will render contents through htmlwriter... i  sow some code from google like create child control.like that ..

Comment: i need custom control like that '<div> </div><div><gridview> </gridview> </div>'..like that i need to render .its posible .please help me..