# create composite control in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create composite and custom grid control in ASP.Net 2008 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497658/create-composite-and-custom-grid-control-in-asp-net-2008-or-above)

I need to create composite control . My control like one "div" inside that div one Gridview control .Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What does the `composite` mean?

Comment: Are you looking for `UserControls`?

Comment: Please edit and improve your questions, don't re-post.

Comment: @Servy Its not a user control .i need Custom control.

Comment: @Evanc3 Composite mean ..creating new custom  control from a build in controls.

Answer (score 1):

Your options for encapsulating UI components are

**User controls**

1. Inherit from UserControl object
2. Must use them in the same project in Visual Studio
3. Will need to expose the events and properities of the gridview
   manually.
4. Can build up from separate webcontrols

See [here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/) for tutorial

**Composite controls**

1. Inherit from CompositeControl
2. Can use in different project in Visual Studio
3. Can build up from separate webcontrols
4. Will need to expose the events and properities of the gridview manually.
5. No UI in Visual Studio designer. Need to include in toolbar to use

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea.aspx) for tutorial

**Inherited Control**

1. Inherit from GridView (in your case)
2. Can use in different project in Visual Studio
3. One control only (the grid view)
4. Events and properties exposed automatically
5. No UI in Visual Studio designer. Need to include in toolbar to use

See here for a [tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/pfc/extendservercontrol.asp) (extending a `Textbox` rather than a `GridView`)

From what you describe it looks like the Inherited control option that you should go for

Answer (score 0):

You could write a control adapter that takes a `GridView` and renders it how you would like.

http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/GridView.aspx